# Which field takes precedence when tagging a file binary?

Tags: linux, unix, binary

When I look at the internal information of a file I have found two fields, one called CCSID which contains the encoding of the file and another called FILEFMT containing the format of the file. Unfortunately, both fields have a "binary" indicator.

A CCSID of 0xFFFF means binary, as does a FileFMT of 0x01.   Unfortunately they seem to be independently controlled.

I've seen a CCSID of ISO8859-1 (ASCII) and FileFMT binary, and also other files with a CCSID of BINARY with a FileFMT of CRLF.

I am confused.  What field takes precedence ?

Regards,
Gary